# How to properly display a list in a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Please tell me if I set this up wrong:

Model:

```
public List<double> Balance { get; set; } = new List<double>();

public List<double> MonthlyPrincipal { get; set; } = new List<double>();
    
public List<double> MonthlyInterest { get; set; } = new List<double>();

public List<double> AccumulativeInterest { get; set; } = new List<double>();
```

Controller:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= T; i++)
{
    //math                
    double interest = balance * (R / 1200);
    double principalPayment = monthlyPayment - interest;                       
    double interestTotal = (balance + interest) - balance;
    balance = balance - principalPayment; 
    cumulative = cumulative + interest;                     

    //Pushing math to arrays.
    balanceArray.Add(balance);
    interestArray.Add(interestTotal);
    principalpaymentArray.Add(principalPayment);
    cumulativeArray.Add(cumulative);
}
model.MonthlyPrincipal = principalpaymentArray;
model.Balance = balanceArray;
model.MonthlyInterest = interestArray;
model.AccumulativeInterest = cumulativeArray;
```

View:

```
<tbody>
    @for (var i = 1; i <= Model.Term; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@i</td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Payment)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MonthlyPrincipal)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MonthlyInterest)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccumulativeInterest)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Balance)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Now what this is doing is printing every item in the array in the table columns. How do correct this?

Comment: When you say 'How do correct this?', what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Jonathan Its displaying as every item in the array instead of <td>item1</td>.

Comment: @mason So I changed over to a foreach loop but all the list items are still suck together is [this wrong?](https://prnt.sc/MsJjfUlm6BD_)

Comment: You should use `model.Payment[i]`, `model.MonthlyPrincipal[i]` and so on

Comment: @Chetan Should that be used with the for loop or the foreach loop?

Comment: You are already using for loop... just use in that.

Comment: You have 4 list items. U can't literate only with 1 loop. What is the expected end result? Can u show in a image diagram? I doubt the view model is making sense.

Comment: @YatFeiLeong https://prnt.sc/2LWTP1zgxXsj Here is the expected result. I agree my approach is definitely wrong from what I've learned so far but I can't figure out how to combine the lists or if I should've just added them to one list to begin with.

Comment: hi @Riokei . It is not complicated. You need to reconfigure your model. I'll try to post an answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the model you should be having. One for the loan payment transaction. The other one is the view model to display the result as shown

```
public class LoanPaymentVM
    {
        public decimal BFBalance { get; set; }
        public List<LoadPayment>? LoadPayments { get; set; }

        public LoanPaymentVM()
        {
            BFBalance = 0;
            LoadPayments = new List<LoadPayment>();
        }
    }

    public class LoadPayment
    {
            public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
            public decimal PayAmt { get; set; }
            public decimal Interest { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Your controller should be very simple. Just put in the loan payment amount and interest will do. The calculation can be done one the view. Well you may pre-calculate the balance here though but that's all up to you.

```
public ActionResult LoanPayment() {

            LoanPaymentVM _lvm = new LoanPaymentVM();

            //Mock data for result

            _lvm.BFBalance = 10000;
            _lvm.LoadPayments.Add(
              new LoadPayment { PaymentDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-2), PayAmt = 1000, Interest = 50 }
              );

            _lvm.LoadPayments.Add(
                new LoadPayment { PaymentDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1), PayAmt = 1000, Interest = 50 }
                );
            _lvm.LoadPayments.Add(
              new LoadPayment { PaymentDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1), PayAmt = 1000, Interest = 50 }
              );
            // Mock data completed



            return View(_lvm);
        }
```

And here comes the View. **For the variable Balance and AccInterest I defined, you may have to add @ depending what version of VS you are using.**

there goes the view

```
@{
    decimal AccInterest = 0;
    decimal Balance = 0;
}

@{Balance = Model.BFBalance;}

<table class="table table-striped">

    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Payment</th>
        <th>Interest</th>
        <th>AccInterest</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Opening Balance</td>
        <td>@Model.BFBalance</td>
    </tr>
   
    @foreach (var item in Model.LoadPayments)
    {
        AccInterest = AccInterest + item.Interest;
        Balance = Balance - (item.PayAmt - item.Interest);

        <tr>
            <td>@item.PaymentDate.ToLongDateString()</td>
            <td>@item.PayAmt</td>
            <td>@item.Interest</td>
            <td>@AccInterest</td>
            <td>@Balance</td>
        </tr>
```